Atomically allocate a node in a sparse voxel oct tree
I am running into a tricky situation. I have SVO and I am trying to allocated nodes to it in a multithreaded setting. The representation I have is, in pesudocode
Node {
  data,
  children: [u32; 8]
}

SVO {
   nodes: Vec<Node>
   counter: AtomicU32
}

Assume u32::MAX denote sthat a child is unset The logic, in single threading I would use here would be:
 if SVO.children[index] == u32::MAX
{
    id = SVO.counter.atomic_increment();
    SVO.children[index] = id
    SVO.nodes[id] = new_item
}

But in a MT setting this won't work, because you would need to:

Read the child value
Check if it is u32::MAX
If it is, atomically write to the counter variable

That is, in a single atomic you need to read from one place, check for a conditional then write to an entirely different place. I don't think this can be done atomically (compare_exchange is not enough).
A silly solution is to busy wait based on a dummy reserved value, something like:
while SVO.nodes[node_index].child[id].atomic_read() == u32::MAX - 1 {}

So that you can use compare exchange to block all other threads while you figure out what node you need to write your value into. I, however, don't like this because it's waisting resources and acting as a poor man's mutex. I don't want to lock,
Is it possible to do it without locking?

You forgot to add a tag describing programming language involved to your question. Without such tag visibility of the question is quite low.
